# Suprimir una cadena de array en Java

Tags: java

Hola:necesito ayuda respecto a suṕrimir  una cadena es decir : mi cadena es Java.lang.String y quiero que solo la palabra String quede.He probado varias cosas pero sin exito, por ejemplo el subString 
Podrian ayudarme ?

Comment: Podrías colocar el código Java de lo que has intentado, para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: si, es este codigo en le cual esta leyendo un archivo cvs.Lo que hace es entre otras cosas concatenar dos columnas por ejemplo pero en la parte donde quiero eliminar la cadena Java.Lang.String del campo no lo logro hacer :

Comment: hola, @Hayden te recomiendo colocar un ejemplo de lo que has intentado, por otro lado puedes buscar en google como obtener una palabra especifica de una cadena. https://www.javatpoint.com/substring

Comment: String record =linea;
  // Sepapar la linea leída con el separador definido previamente
    String components[] = record.split(".");
       String type[] = components[4] .split(".");
       String finalType = type[type.length -1];
       String name = components[1] + components[3];
       String description = components[0];

Comment: en la linea :       String finalType = type[type.length -1]; suprimiria pero veo que no lo hace sigue saliendo java.lang.String y quiero que quede solo la palabra String cuando exporto el archivo

Comment: Mas que suprimir lo que necesitas es obtener un texto de una cadena, puedes ver el siguiente ejemplo http://tpcg.io/RSjqIqHR de como obtener una cadena con el método substring.

Comment: @Hayden, de todas maneras, te recomiendo que hagas el recorrido, y busques como editar tu pregunta para poder agregar tu código, mientras mas asertivo sea el titulo de tu pregunta y la pregunta en si, recibirás mas respuestas positivas, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Esto es una manera, de muchas:

```
String record = "Java.lang.String";
String components[] = record.split("\\.");
String type = components[2];
System.out.println(type);
```

Comment: el tema es que me  esta pidiendo el lengh ();

Comment: @Hayden editado

Answer (score 0):

Mas que suprimir una cadena necesita obtener un texto de una cadena, esto lo puedes hacer de muchas formas, una es usando el metodo substring de la clase String

```
public class HelloWorld{
     public static void main(String []args){

        // EJEMPLO UNO
        String str1="java.lang.String";  
        System.out.println(str1.substring(10,16));

        // EJEMPLO DOS
        String str2="java.lang.String";  
        System.out.println(str2.substring(10));
     }
}
```

como funciona substring te lo ejemplifico con una imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En el ejemplo 1 solo contamos empezamos desde la posición 10 y terminamos en la posición 16 es decir que el texto que te traerá sera "STRING".

O bien en el ejemplo 2 solo le dices que te traiga todo lo que vienes después de la posición 10.